# Linux PHP crashing on error-reporting

Tags: php

Basically, I have an issue whenever PHP should show an error; it won't load the .php file at all.

For example, let's say that I make a mistake while writing:

```
<?php 
       function foo($value) { return $value; };
       foo(); //missing value, should display a warning or error
?>
```

That won't show an error, it will just say "This page isnt working".

I checked my php.ini file, but what I found inside seems legit:

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

What could be the cause of this issue? And of course, how to solve it?

Comment: add this at function to your php script `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if it works !

Comment: Have you looked inside the web server error log file?

Comment: @timino nope doesnt work :(

Comment: @nick yes I did, nothing inside of it

Comment: is your apache running correctly ?

Comment: When you say 'nothing' do you mean nothing at all or just nothing relating to this problem?

Comment: @Nick well nothing, I mean the logging works, I got some old errors laying around but no new ones

Comment: Oh, okay. This error is usually an internal server error, so I was wondering if it was having trouble creating an error log entry.

Comment: What happens if you run the script on the command line on the server?

Comment: Have you checked in your php.ini that display_errors is set to On?
If it's set to Off php will only log your errors and warnings in log file and not show in screen.
You can do a quick check by adding at the top pf your php script this directive: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably looking at the wrong error log file.

For PHP there are basically 3 options, depending on what `error_log` in `php.ini` is set to. To determine the correct value, add a file with the contents `<php phpinfo();` and open it in your browser. This should show a list of all php settings. I recommend this method instead of just opening php.ini because it avoids confusion that might be caused by multiple php.ini and conf.d files.

In that page, search for `error_log`. This setting determines your log location. If it is **not set**, that means that PHP is logging to the SAPI interface. Look in your your webserver logs (location depends on OS and used webserver, for Ubuntu and Apache it would be `/var/log/apache2/error.log`).

If there is a file path in `error_log` that is the path of your PHP error log. Just open it and the error should be there.

If `error_log` is set to `syslog`, PHP logs to your system log. For windows, that is the event log (can be opened by searching for "event log" from the taskbar). For Unix that is the syslog, usually `/var/log/syslog` but might vary depending on configuration and distro.

Please note that in case you are using php-fpm there are additional FPM log settings, which you also would need to check.